# How to add a space before the varblock?

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}

\newenvironment<>{varblock}[2][.9\textwidth]{%
  \setlength{\textwidth}{#1}
  \begin{actionenv}#3%
    \def\insertblocktitle{#2}%
    \par%
    \usebeamertemplate{block begin}}
  {\par%
    \usebeamertemplate{block end}%
  \end{actionenv}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\small Backstepping\normalsize}
\begin{columns}[t]
\column{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics<1->[width=7cm,height=3.8cm]{ex0.jpg}\\
\includegraphics<1->[width=7cm,height=3.8cm]ex0.jpg}
\column{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics<1->[width=7cm,height=3.8cm]{ex0.jpg}\\
\hfill\small \begin{varblock}[6.5cm]{\color{blue!90!white}{}}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item<1-> Convergence rapide de la trajectoire réelle vers celle désirée
    \item<1-> Les erreurs sur les positions sont relativement élevées et présentent des variations qui sont traduites par des dérivées très importantes
    \end{itemize}
  \end{varblock}\normalsize
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Before which box?

Comment: the varblock of course

Comment: Your images are wider than your columns. If you adjust their size to stay in their columns, you need neither the varblock nor add space in front of it. Please also note that two columns of .5\textwidth each don't fit on the frame. Either make them a bit smaller (e.g. .48\textwidth) or use `\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]`

Comment: @Elyes Do you want to add horizontal or vertical space. You tagged your question with `vspace`, but based on the code, I would have guessed horizontal space? (I had to replace the images, because obviously I don't have your images, so I cannot be sure if I see the same layout as you)

Comment: Also specifying both the width and the height of an image is usually not a good idea, this will distort the image. Only specify either the width or the height, not both.

Comment: yes it's a hspace

Comment: @Elyes If you reply to a comment, please include @ followed by the user name. This way the user will get notified of your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would use a suitable size for your images, so that they actually fit inside their column without overlapping each other, you would not need to use a `varblock` nor add additional space in front of it:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}

\usecolortheme{orchid}

\begin{document}

\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\small}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Backstepping}
    \begin{columns}[T]
        \begin{column}{.49\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-16x10}

            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-16x10}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.49\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-16x10}

            \begin{block}{Title}
                \settowidth{\leftmargini}{\usebeamertemplate{itemize item}}
                \addtolength{\leftmargini}{\labelsep}
                \setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate body}{size=\footnotesize}
                \begin{itemize}
                \item Convergence rapide de la trajectoire réelle vers celle désirée
                \item Les erreurs sur les positions sont relativement élevées et présentent des variations qui sont traduites par des dérivées très importantes
            \end{itemize}
        \end{block}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]